# Header error in displaying API output

Tags: php

I am creating an API where the output will be in json format. I am getting the required output but with header error that too when i upload on the server.
There are no whitespace in my script and i have also tried putting ob_start and ob_end_clean() at the start and end of my script but of no use.

Here i am calling one API within other API will that be the cause for this header problem?

Is there any other method to get rid of this error? Please help.

```
public function userinteract(){ 
    $usersData = new TeleDataModel();
    $dataArr = $this->_readJSON();
    //print_r($dataArr);
    //------Get the mobile number------- //
    if ($dataArr['mobile']==''){
        $outputArr["check"] = "failed";
        $outputArr["message"] = "Please enter your mobile number with ISD Code..";
        $this->_writeJSON($outputArr);
         return;
    }
    //--------Check if call is from India, if call is out of India then reject call--------//
    $mobile=$dataArr['mobile']; 
    $mobile=urlencode($mobile);
    if(substr($mobile,0,3)== "+91"){
        //------Remove +91 from given number--------//
        $mobile=preg_replace("/\+91/", '', $mobile);
        //--------Check if user is registered or not---------//
        a:$checkVerify=$usersData->checkExistingUser($mobile,''); 
        if(count($checkVerify) > 0){
            for($i=0;$i<count($checkVerify);$i++){
                $firstname=$checkVerify[$i]['firstname'];
            }
            if($firstname==''){
                echo ('Not a registered user');
                $check=$usersData->checkunregistered($mobile);
                if($check!=0 && count($check)>0){
                    for($i=0;$i<count($check);$i++){
                        $count=$check[$i]['count'];
                        if(($count==1)||($count==2)||($count==3)){
                            $ch = curl_init(); 
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://xyz dot com/folder/tele/adSelection");  //call to another API
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"mobile=$mobile");
                            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                            $result = curl_exec($ch);
                            print_r($result);
                            curl_close($ch);  
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                $outputArr['message']="No previous call records...";
                $this->_writeJSON($outputArr);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update: This is the error I am getting:

Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/xyz/public_html/folder/Controller.php:339) in /home/xyz/public_html/folder/Controller.php on line 338

There is a seperate function for _writeJSON and the code is:

```
private function _writeJSON($outputArr) {           
    $json = json_encode($outputArr);
    header("Content-Type: application/json"); // line number 399
    echo $json; 
}
```

Comment: `Here i am calling one API within other API will that be the cause for this header problem? `? where? put your code here

Comment: `a:$checkVerify=$usersData->checkExistingUser($mobile,''); ` these code seems not correct

Comment: Also what error you are getting and at which line? put both here in your question by editing it.

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/5420829. Please tell if it helps.

Comment: I have gone through the above suggested link. Yes it was helpful.

Comment: The issue is solved, there was a whitespace after the end of php tag in one of the file which was causing the error.